# "We started" or "We've started" or "We've been started"?

Tags: grammar

My question is: which one is correct in this sentence?
"A couple of months ago we -started- rehearsing again."
So the point is, we didn't specify the exact date and the activity is still going on.

I'd also be grateful if you'd tell me the differences between the 3 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give a time phrase "A couple of months ago". This specifies a past time, so you must use the past tense. "We started" is past tense. It doesn't matter that the phrase isn't precise. It still refers to a time in the past.

If you don't use a time expression you could use either past tense or perfect tense. Both are correct. The past tense talks about a past action. The perfect tense "We've started rehearsing again" talks about the current state (as a result of the past action) But there is not much difference and both could be used.

"We've been started" is a passive form. It means "Something has started us". That doesn't make sense in the context.